# How to ensure that the code below call back always runs after call back finishes

Tags: javascript, typescript

The set interval runs the code again and again. The `console.log("2")` is printed before `console.log("1")`, I want to run it sequentially

```
let repeat = setInterval(() => {
    let index = 0
    let file = { Id: this.g[index].id }
    this.auth.verifyProgress(file).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            running = ....;
            if (!running) {
                clearInterval(repeat)
            }
            console.log('1')
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        }
    )
    index = index + 1
    if (index >= numberOfFiles) {
        index = 0
    }
    console.log('2')
}, 4000)
```

I don't want to put the code outside, inside the success callback because I want to run it regardless if res or err. What should I do.

Can it be done using promise or await ?

Comment: You don't. You put the code that you want to run later inside the callback (in your case, after the `clearInterval()`).

Comment: corrected..........

Answer (score -1):

> I want to run it regardless if res or err

Put the code into a function, call that function in both cases.